# Архивирование и разархивирование файлов

Tags: java, zip

У меня есть метод, который, при вводе пути к *zip*, должен разархивировать файлы, но он не работает.
В чем причина?

```
package Programm;    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;

public class Unzip {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String zipDir  = "Тестовая папка";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String zipFile = "Тестовая папка.zip";

    private final String SLASH_BACK     = "/";

    private void createDir(final String dir)
    {
        File file = new File(dir);
        if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdirs();
    }

    private void createFolder(final String dirName)
    {
        if (dirName.endsWith(SLASH_BACK))
            createDir(dirName.substring(0, dirName.length() - 1));
    }

    private void checkFolder(final String file_path)
    {
        if (!file_path.endsWith(SLASH_BACK) && file_path.contains(SLASH_BACK)) {
            String dir = file_path.substring(0, file_path.lastIndexOf(SLASH_BACK));
            createDir(dir);
        }
    }

    Unzip(final String zipDir) throws Exception
    {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipDir);
        Enumeration<?> entries = zipFile.getEntries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
            String entryName = entry.getName();
            if (entryName.endsWith(SLASH_BACK)) {
                System.out.println("Создание директории <" + entryName + ">");
                createFolder (entryName);
                continue;
            } else
                checkFolder(entryName);
            System.out.println("Чтение файла <" + entryName + ">");
            InputStream  fis = (InputStream) zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entryName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
            // Считываем буфер
            fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // Записываем из буфера в файл
            fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        }
        zipFile.close() ;      
        System.out.println("Zip файл разархивирован!");
    }
}
```

Также есть метод, который запаковывает файлы из одного до другого пути.
Почему при архивировании в *zip* файле указывается полный путь?

```
package Programm;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Zip {
    Zip(String source_dir, String zip_file) throws Exception
    {
        // Cоздание объекта ZipOutputStream из FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zip_file);
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
        // Определение кодировки
        //zout.setEncoding("CP866");

        // Создание объекта File object архивируемой директории
        File fileSource = new File(source_dir);

        addDirectory(zout, fileSource);

        // Закрываем ZipOutputStream
        zout.close();

        System.out.println("Zip файл создан!");
    }

    private void addDirectory(ZipOutputStream zout, File fileSource) 
                                                    throws Exception
    {
        File[] files = fileSource.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Добавление директории <" + fileSource.getName() + ">");
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            // Если file является директорией, то рекурсивно вызываем 
            // метод addDirectory
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                addDirectory(zout, files[i]);
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Добавление файла <" + files[i].getName() + ">");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath()));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4048];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            // Закрываем ZipOutputStream и InputStream
            zout.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: вот такой путь и далее идет до папки]

Comment: Нашел ответ тут. Всем спасибо. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399126/java-util-zip-recreating-directory-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String entryName = entry.getName();
```

Имя файла внутри архива содержит путь относительно архива.

Т.е. если в архиве есть папка `new` и там файл `ping.png`, то `entry.getName()` вернет `new/ping.png`.

Потом вы создаете поток для записи в файл `new/ping.png`:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entryName);
```

Но в `windows` корневыми папками являются диски, вы пытаетесь разархивировать архив на уровень корневых папок (дисков).

Вам надо указать куда разархивировать относительно корня файловой системы.
Как вариант, можете хардкодом указать, либо принимать параметр указывающий путь к папке.

```
String ouputFolder = "C/архив/";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ouputFolder + entryName);
```

---

При упаковке файла в архив вы берете полный путь файла

```
  zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath()));
```

А полный путь файла включает все директории относительно корневого каталога (диска С). Поэтому при архивации ZipEntry надо прописывать путь относительно архива.

С помощью метода Path.relativize вы можете получить относительный путь

```
Path zip = ...//путь к архиву
Path file = ...//путь к файлу
Path fileInArchiv = zip.relativize(file) // путь к фалу относительно архива
zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileInArchiv));
```

Comment: Т.е. Раз архивация должна быть по пути?

Comment: да вы должны указать, где создавать разархивированный файл

Comment: У меня при архивации в архиве диск с: указывается и т.д. куча папок вполть до файлов. Мне нужно что бы последние 2 директории упаковывало в архив. (вообщем конкретную папку надо упаковать). Это не так страшно ? и почему так запаковывается?

Comment: ответ допишу в пост, т.к. в комментариях код потеряется

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснили. А почему выдавало ошибку на 40 строке 
Enumeration<?> entries = zipFile.getEntries();  Подчеркивало красным .getEntries();???

Comment: какую конкретно ошибку?

Comment: Я просто за основу код взял и другой программы, так как не спец по zip архивированию

Comment: Метод getEntries() не определен для типа ZipFile - вот эта ошибка выделяет красным .getEntries();

Comment: у класса ZipFile нет метода getEntries, есть только entries (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries())